# gradle is missing ? i cant see gradle in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-gradle-plugin, mobile-application

I'm new to android. I have just finished downloading android studio and I am now setting up setting up gradle.

I think gradle is missing or my computer hasn't seen it yet. I am not sure and do not know how to solve this.

[image: gradle is missing - android studio screenshot]

Comment: Try reopening studio again.It might be due to failure in downloading dependency.

Comment: I have the same issue, Gradle doesn't show in the SDK Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment. Am I to just homebrew it myself?

Answer (score 1):

Below src you see Project you are viewing project files,click to see dropdown and change it to android.You will see updates gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean, rebuild and invalidate and restart the project.

If it still does not solve your issue, go to gradle module and try using different versions of gradle and make your minSDK to 15 and compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion to same versions. Try re-syncing.

If it still does not solve your issue, you might have problem with SDK. Try updating it to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

in the left column select project and click on that dropdown and change that to android and then it will show the gradle files. you have selected project so it shows the complete files and libraries or the project.
Happy coding!